# Asp.Net Routing with different parameter names

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-areas

I'm trying to map certain routes so that auto generated Urls will look like
`Admin/controller/action/param` for both of these code blocks,
`@Url.Action("action","controller",new{id="param"})` and
`@Url.Action("action","controller",new{type="param"})`

What I did was the following in the area registration,

```
context.MapRoute(
            "Admin_default",
            "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", 
                  id = UrlParameter.Optional }, 
            new string[] { "namespaces" });

        context.MapRoute(
            "Admin_type",
            "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{type}",
            new { action = "Index", 
                  type = UrlParameter.Optional }, 
            new string[] { "namespaces" });
```

when parameter name is `id`, url generated is as expected, but when parameter name is `type`, instead of `controller/action/typevalue`, it generates something like `controller/action/?type=typevalue`

Is there a way to generate the url something like `controller/action/typevalue` keeping the generator behaviour for `Admin_default` route intact?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> when parameter name is id, url generated is as expected, but when
>   parameter name is type, instead of controller/action/typevalue, it
>   generates something like controller/action/?type=typevalue

That happens because first route is used to map the url (id is optional).

You could try adding some constraints to your routes. I'm guessing your id parameter is an integer and type parameter is a string. In that case you can try with this routes:

```
context.MapRoute(
                "Admin_default",
                "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, 
                new { id = @"\d+" },    
                new string[] { "namespaces" });

context.MapRoute(
                "Admin_type",
                "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{type}",
                new { action = "Index", type = UrlParameter.Optional }, 
                new string[] { "namespaces" });
```

You can find more info on route constraints [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/creating-a-route-constraint-cs).

Comment: Thank you. That worked as expected with all urls in expected format. Never looked into route constraints.. my bad..! Thanks anyway. Accepted your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried removing the Optional default value on id ? In this case, the first route shouldn't match when providing only the type parameter.

EDIT: After reading again your question, my solution doesn't keep your first route intact ...

Answer (score 0):

You only need the one route.

```
context.MapRoute("Admin_default",             
         "Admin/{action}/{id}",            
         new { action = "Index",                    
         id = UrlParameter.Optional },              
        new string[] { "namespaces" });
```

in your controller you

URLs:
http://website/Admin/index/hello

http://website/Admin/type/342

```
public class AdminController()
{
   public ActionResult Index(string id)
   {
     // do whatever
     returne View();
   }

   public ActionResult type(string id)
   {
     // do whatever
     returne View();
   }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm talking about parameters not actions.